# Rails 4 - Devise confirmable, in certain conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

I'm trying to figure out if I can use devise confirmable to achieve the following outcome.

I have a user model. When a new user registers (I use devise), I have a service class in my user model that checks if their email address matches the format of any organisation's email address that is already registered. For example, if joe@blogs.com registers, I check if www.blogs.com is already registered as an organisation that uses the format of email address that Joe has used to register, and I then add Joe to that organisation.

Devise confirmable works to send the confirmation email to Joe.

However, if I don't recognise www.blogs.com, I want to use an admin approval process where the newly registered Joe, shouldn't receive a confirmation token from devise confirmable - instead, it should go to an admin to manually approve Joe as a user.

Is there a way I can use devise confirmable in certain circumstances (an email address that matches an organisations web email format)?

Comment: You need to override devises Devise::ConfirmationsController create method. I don't have time to give a full answer now but start looking here: 

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Override-confirmations-so-users-can-pick-their-own-passwords-as-part-of-confirmation-activation

It's not the same goal but the process of overriding and modifying the default behavior (e.g validate the email and redirect according to yes/no) will happen in the same place.

Comment: @RichardAE Thanks for the tip - ill look at into it